# Topics enabled for objects not getting deployed to packaging org

Tags: apex, lightning, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

While trying to deploy TopicsForObjects in the packaging org I receive the following Error:

> Error  metadata/package.xml  package.xml  You cannot install or
>   upgrade a package that has a TopicsForObjects component. Remove
>   components of TopicsForObjects type from the package.

The Topics have been enabled in Salesforce Classic and are enabled on a Custom Object.

The deploy is done via those two commands and after the second one the Error occurs:

1. `sfdx force:source:convert`
2. `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy`

Maybe it's not possible to deploy Settings from Salesforce Classic to a Lightning Experience App or why is the Error thrown here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following answer came from the SF-Support:

> I have had a discussion with the internal teams here. Based on what we checked, It seems that the error you are seeing is expected since the topicsForSobject is not available under the documentation.
>
> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm
>
> That is the reason we were seeing the error to remove the component.
>
> The workaround which you are following as of now should be a viable soln until we have this under the allowed list.
>   I did indeed check for any roadmap / ETA of this being available however, we did not find any information regarding the same.

The mentioned Workaround is to delete that topicsForObjects.