# Dynamically create TopicsForObjects metadata from Apex

Tags: apex, managed-package, metadata-api, isv, topics

Whenever I am [unable to package a certain metadata type](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/301730) in a Managed Page I created them from a Setup page after installation using the Metadata API and [this neat Apex Wrapper lib](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/).

But this time I seem to be out of luck. The [TopicsForObjects metadata type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_topicsforobjects.htm) is not covered by this lib. Any other way to do it (simpler)? Without manually patching the lib?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see TopicsForObjects in apex-mdapi. This is the below snippet from their code and taken from what's available in their github.

```
public class TopicsForObjects extends Metadata {
        public String type = 'TopicsForObjects';
        public String fullName;
        private String[] fullName_type_info = new String[]{'fullName',SOAP_M_URI,null,'0','1','false'};
        public Boolean enableTopics;
        public String entityApiName;
        private String[] enableTopics_type_info = new String[]{'enableTopics',SOAP_M_URI,null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] entityApiName_type_info = new String[]{'entityApiName',SOAP_M_URI,null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{SOAP_M_URI,'true','false'};
        private String[] type_att_info = new String[]{'xsi:type'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'fullName', 'enableTopics','entityApiName'};
    }
```

I was also able to update the TopicsForObjects record for a given object that was disabled. I successfully flipped it to "enabled".

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
List<String> objectNames= new List<String>{'Account_Group__c'}; //add your objects api name here

//Get TopicForObject metadata records
List<MetadataService.TopicsForObjects> topicForObjectRecs = (List<MetadataService.TopicsForObjects>) service.readMetadata('TopicsForObjects', objectNames).getRecords();

//enable topics for given object
topicForObjectRecs[0].enableTopics = true;

//update metadata
List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results =
        service.updateMetadata(
                new MetadataService.Metadata[] { topicForObjectRecs[0] });
```